# ex/vi: Input encoding conversion not supported

Tags: freebsd, vi

I've a problem with `vi`, every time I launched it I get this message:

```
Input encoding conversion not supported; /tmp/vi.PSzqmm9ox9: new file: line 1
```

Despite this message I'm able to edit and save the file. (The message repeats again when I save it.) If I open the file and close it without making any changes, the message is printed when `vi` exits, in my terminal.

Unfortunately, I have to fix that without re-installing `vi`.

`Vi` version: Version 2.1.2 (2012-11-02)

`FreeBSD` version: 10.1-RELEASE-p9

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use `file` to see if there are any hints on what the file is; otherwise, `hexdump` the file and look for high-bit or otherwise unprintable characters?

Comment: Thanks for your time @thrig. My example file is in plain ASCII according to `file`. I should have precise that this message appears with every file.

Comment: Hmm, not sure. The output of `locale` might be handy to look at, whether `vi` is aliased to anything, and whether the encoding on any existing files mentioned in the `FILES` section of `vi(1)` is not ASCII.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
vi -cset\ fe=iso-8859-1 your.file
```

This will force nvi to assume ISO-8859-1 charset instead of autodetecting the apparently wrong charset.